# Getting output from cmd command in java

Tags: java, windows, cmd, process

I'm trying to get the exe associated with a file type in Java. I'm doing this by launching a cmd process that does assoc and trying to capture the output of it. Now this is where things go wrong, I get the following lines coming through but nothing else:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.648]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Here is my code:

```
        String[] commands = {"cmd", "assoc .txt"};
        final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
        Process pr = pb.start();
        pr.getOutputStream().close();

        BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getErrorStream()));

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

        String s;
        while((s = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        String error;
        while((error = errorReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(error);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be that you use `BufferedReader.readLine()`. This waits for a line break, which may not be sent by your process.
Also, you run everything in one Thread, that can hamper your catching of the output.
Have a look at **3.** on https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/processbuilder/java-lang-processbuilder-example/